# react-native using expo-av IOS recorded mp4 file form data call to openai's audio transcriptions saying invalid file format

Tags: typescript, react-native, api, expo, openai-api

I've been at this all night, I'm attempting to record myself on my iPhone via expo using expo-av (records speech via iPhone) and upload it to openai's transcriptions endpoint using whisper-1 model.

The file is saved as mp4, I convert it to a base64 string, I have confirmed the base64 content is infact mp4:

**base64 to file converting tool**

[image]

**uploading and checking file tool**

[image]

Here's the react-native code:

```
  const recordingOptions = {
    android: {
      extension: ".mp4",
      outputFormat: Audio.AndroidOutputFormat.MPEG_4,
      audioEncoder: Audio.AndroidAudioEncoder.AAC,
      sampleRate: 44100,
      numberOfChannels: 2,
      bitRate: 128000,
    },
    ios: {
      extension: ".mp4",
      // outputFormat: Audio.IOSOutputFormat.MPEG4AAC,
      audioQuality: Audio.IOSAudioQuality.HIGH,
      sampleRate: 44100,
      numberOfChannels: 2,
      bitRate: 128000,
    },
    web: {
      mimeType: "audio/mp4",
      bitsPerSecond: 128000 * 8,
    },
  };
```

**actual implementation:**

```
const recordingUri = recording.getURI();
      const recordingBase64 = await ExpoFileSystem.readAsStringAsync(
        recordingUri,
        {
          encoding: ExpoFileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
        }
      );
      const languageCode = "en"; // English
      console.log(languageCode);
      console.log(recordingBase64)

      const buffer = Buffer.from(recordingBase64, "base64")
      const blob= new Blob([buffer], { type:'audio/mp4' })
      const file = new File([blob],'test.mp4', {type:'audio/mp4'})



      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file',file);
      formData.append("model", "whisper-1");

      const apiUrl = "https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions";

      const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${OPENAI_API_KEY}`,
        },
        body: formData,
      };

      fetch(apiUrl, requestOptions)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

and every time the response is:

```
{"error": {"code": null, "message": "Invalid file format. Supported formats: ['m4a', 'mp3', 'webm', 'mp4', 'mpga', 'wav', 'mpeg']", "param": null, "type": "invalid_request_error"}}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem.  Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @MichaelCeber I ended up passing this base64 to my node backend and using the Buffer class to write the file then read it via fs.createReadStream and pass that to openai's node library.

Comment: Ahh funny, as after I sent this message, thats exactly what I did, moved it off the UI and to the back end code which was reliable (my back end though is c#) - was always going to put it in the back end anyway as need to secure the api key etc there...

Comment: @MichaelCeber yeah man I tried everything, something's up with the Buffer implementation on the client side for this scenario. glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a `filename` to the `formData.append`. Something similar to this:

```
formData.append('file', file, 'input.mp4');
```

Whisper shouldn't rely on the extension, but it seems like it does.

Comment: Yes, I confirm this is a good answer, had the same issue and solved it like that.

Comment: I tried adding the filename with the above implementation but my code fails when defining the blob. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76367660/react-native-using-expo-av-ios-mp4-file-openais-audio-transcriptions-invalid-fi